# UITextField is not filing available width inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, uistackview

I want to put two buttons with images on left and right edges of the screen, and insert a `UITextField` between them. In `storyboard` everything is fine, but I need to do it programmatically.

Source:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    let leftButton = UIButton()
    leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "first"), for: .normal)
    leftButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    
    let rightButton = UIButton()
    rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "second"), for: .normal)
    rightButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.placeholder = "clear"
    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    textField.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
    
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 15

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(leftButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(textField)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(rightButton)
    
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 15).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -15).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50).isActive = true
    
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I need a result like on first image.

[image: I need result like this]

But at result, I have second.
[image: but got this]

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an elementary constraint ambiguity. You could easily have discovered this just by switching to the View Debugger; you would see three exclamation marks warning you of the problem. The layout engine does not magically know which of the three views should be allowed to stretch horizontally. You have to tell it:

```
textField.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(249), for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. I am limited in some xcode instruments, because I am using Xamarin.iOS and re-write my issue to swift. P.S. That is why, i am still using semicolons :)

Answer (score 2):

Set constraints like

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50),
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45),
    leftButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30), 
    rightButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
])
```

Another small change

```
rightButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
leftButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats also works, but @matt solutions is what i am looked for